# What would be the best solution to fix Error 1009 in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've created our thesis about android game using Adobe Animate CC 2015. When I go to the main game, my character walked, the questionnaire appears, and then the "Correct!" window appears, so all of it exists in frame 75. So in the "Correct!" window has "Go" button, when I clicked it I've got received error 1009. It supposed to be when I clicked "Go" button, it supposed to be proceed in frame 76. So here's the message:

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_diemgeym_fla::MainTimeline/frame76()[RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_diemgeym_fla.MainTimeline::frame76:21]
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at QuizQuest2()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_diemgeym_fla::MainTimeline/gura()[RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_diemgeym_fla.MainTimeline::frame75:108]`

Here are my codes (actually I separated these but all of these are exist in frame 76 but I combined it altogether):

```
stop();
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.Stage;
//import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var goiX = playergril2.x;
var goiY = playergril2.y;
pausewin2.visible = false;
corekWin2.visible = false;
maliWin2.visible = false;
btnGub.visible = false;
quizQuest2.visible = false;

btnForward2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setpositionz);

function setpositionz(event: MouseEvent) {
goiX = mouseX;
goiY = mouseY;
playergril2.x += 15;
playergril2.play();
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopz);
}

function loopz(event: Event) {
if (keyCollected == false) {
    if (playergril2.hitTestObject(key2)) {
        key2.visible = false;
        keyCollected = true;
        btnGub.visible = true;
        trace("key collected");
        //removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    }
}
}
 btnGub.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, forwardz);
  function forwardz(event: MouseEvent): void {
    quizQuest2.visible = true;
    playergril2.visible = false;
}

-------
txtSkor2.text = String(iskoru2);
txtLives2.text = String(buhay2);
txtHints2.text = String(hinto2);
quizQuest2.nohint2.visible = false;
var sec2: Number = 15;
quizQuest2.secBox2.text = String(sec2);
var gameTimer2: Timer = new Timer(1000);

gameTimer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countDown2);
gameTimer2.start();


function countDown2(event: TimerEvent): void {
sec2--;
if (sec2 < 0) {
    gameTimer2.stop();
    gameTimer2.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countDown2);
    maliWin2.visible = true;
    quizQuest2.visible = false;
}
}

 quizQuest2.ans21.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones2);
 quizQuest2.ans22.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones2);
 quizQuest2.ans23.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttones2);

function buttones2(event:Event):void{
  if(event.currentTarget == quizQuest2.ans23){
    quizQuest2.visible = false;
    corekWin2.visible = true;
    iskoru2 += 10;
}else if(event.currentTarget == quizQuest2.ans21 || event.currentTarget == quizQuest2.ans22){
    quizQuest2.visible = false;
    maliWin2.visible = true;
    buhay2 -= 1;
}
}

quizQuest2.btnHint2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, woo);
function woo(event: MouseEvent): void {
hinto2 -= 1;
quizQuest2.txtHint2.visible = true;
if (hinto2 == 0) {
    quizQuest2.nohint2.visible = true;
}
}
corekWin2.btnGo2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gura2);

function gura2(event: MouseEvent): void {
corekWin2.visible = false;
quizQuest2.visible = false;
gotoAndStop(77);
}

-------
maliWin2.btnGobak2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bey2);

function bey2(event: MouseEvent): void {
maliWin2.visible = false;
}

------
btnPause2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, oop2);

function oop2(event: MouseEvent): void {
stage.frameRate = 0;
pausewin2.visible = true;

pausewin2.btnResume2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, op2);
pausewin2.btnQtm2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, oip2);
}
function op2(event: MouseEvent): void {
stage.frameRate = 24;
pausewin2.visible = false;
}
function oip2(event: MouseEvent): void {
gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

And the problematic code is: `quizQuest2.visible = false;` so I did permit debugging.
I double-checked all of my codes, objects (movieclips, textfields and buttons), and instance names that are in the frame 76 and all of them are matched even quizQuest2 is already exists in frame 76 but still, I got the error 1009 and I can't figure out why did happen. I really don't know how I'm going fix it.

So I'll provide some screenshots of my GUI here as follows:
1. [The quizQuest2 movieclip with some other movieclips exist in frame 76](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlSg9.jpg)
2. [The pausewin2 with two buttons inside of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agl2T.jpg)

I did provided those screenshots for you to see what's on the frame 76, but it supposed to be 5 screenshots but the 3 others can't because it says that I need 10 reps to upload more. Anyways, what should I do or the best solution on how I fix this problem? I need your help because my thesis defense is almost near. Thank you.

Comment: **trace(currentFrame);** and **trace(quizQuest2);** and **trace(getChildByName("quizQuest2"));** and **for (var i:int = numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--) trace(i, getChildAt(i));** right before error.

Comment: I'll go put them to frame 76 right?

Comment: I did what you said, I put them on frame 76 and these are the results of tracing (I copy and paste them according to your comment):
76
null (refers to trace(quizQuest2);)
[object QuizQuest2]
16 [object QuizQuest2]
15 [object PlayerGril]
14 [object CorekWincopy]
13 [object MaliWincopy]
12 [object PauseWincopy]
11 [object TextField]
10 [object TextField]
9 [object TextField]
8 [object Lives]
7 [object Hinteu]
6 [object Scorer]
5 [object SimpleButton]
4 [object SimpleButton]
3 [object SimpleButton]
2 [object Key]
1 [object Door]
0 [object Room2]

Comment: But still, I got error 1009, same message as above

Comment: It was not a solution, it was a diagnostics. Now, I ask you a guiding question. The **trace(quizQuest2)** outputs **null**. The **trace(getChildByName("quizQuest2"))** outputs **[object QuizQuest2]**. The frame is indeed 76. What does it mean?

Comment: The QuizQuest2 is the name of the object while the quizQuest2 with small 'q' at the beginning is the instance name for QuizQuest2 with big 'Q'. Then.. wait.. when quizQuest2 itself traced becomes null? I really don't get it why it becomes null.

Comment: There's a difference between instance names and current context members. The **getChildByName("quizQuest2")** is a request meaning **get a child with name "quizQuest2" of current display container**. When you put **quizQuest2** you mean **get the current context member or variable** that could be a local variable with that name, or current object (**this**) property with this name. The main part of it, the context member **is not necessarily** a child with the same instance name. That could happen due to various circumstances.

Comment: I don't know why every other child pass their names as members to the timeline, while that quiz does not. As a quickfix you may replace erroneous **quizQuest2** with **getChildByName("quizQuest2")**.

Comment: Still, I got error 1009:
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_diemgeym_fla::MainTimeline/frame76()[RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_diemgeym_fla.MainTimeline::frame76:55]
 at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
 at flash.display::Sprite()
 at flash.display::MovieClip()
 at QuizQuest2()
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
 at RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_diemgeym_fla::MainTimeline/gura()[RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_diemgeym_fla.MainTimeline::frame75:107]

Comment: If you look closer, the error is produced by another line: **::frame76:55**

Comment: Maybe you will need to wrap it as getter: **function get Q2():QuizQuest2 { return getChildByName("quizQuest2") as QuizQuest2; }** and replace **quizQuest2** with **Q2** everywhere where you refer it.

Comment: I did that but I got "duplicate function definition" even if it is not

Comment: If you add one function and get errors, then, I guess, we have to admit that your **RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_RECOVER_** project is kinda beyond repair. Or you might have added it several times to frame 76 but different layers.

Comment: What do you mean by "beyond repair"? And, I've only once added it on a keyframe (a layer) that belongs to frame 76. I've tried to rename its instance name but still an error. I feel insane how I fix this error, and I can't find what is the main cause of the error.

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes, Flash breaks its FLA-projects. I've seen a few times over the years I work with Flash, and I cannot mark these memories as "my favorite". If your FLA weights a lot, if you have a lot of items in the Library, if you have a lot of instances on your timeline, especially text fields.

Comment: Basically. You say, that you **cannot** add a function to a keyframe?